# xslt output xml tree without using xsl:copy

Tags: xslt, tags, output, element

Suppose I had the following xml doc

```
<?xml version="1.0"  ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<a>
<ab x="x"><b>Test</b><a>z</a></ab>
<z x="x"><a>z</a></z>
</a>
```

and I wanted to output on screen only the a elements and their attributes and values while omitting the b element and z element. In other words produce this onscreen. What is the best approach without using xsl:element or xsl:copy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<a>
<ab x="x"><a>z</a></ab>

</a>
```

Comment: You have tagged your question as XSLT. Both `xsl:element` and `xsl:copy` are an integral part of the XSLT language. Asking for a solution that doesn't use them is asking for a solution in a different language. In a previous question of yours , you gave "client's requirement" as the reason for a similar limitation. That's not a good enough reason for me to consider your question. I don't work for your client. It's quite possible that the answer does not require `xsl:element` nor `xsl:copy` - but I don't find the problem interesting enough to find out.

Comment: ok thanks Michael. This is only for myself. I want to out put the contents of a xml document on screen using copy-of or some other method but I am very new to xml and I am struggling with the logic.

Comment: The usual approach is to start with the identity transformation template and then to add a template matching the elements you want to remove, either making that template empty if you want to completely remove those elements or using `apply-templates` if you want to process the children. However the identity template uses `xsl:copy`

Comment: ok thanks Martin. I guess I will use xsl:copy.